# Filter Pandas Dataframe using list, but making sure count of elements matches count in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

so I have a list

```
my_list = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
```

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
col_1    col_2
a        1
b        1
c        2
d        3
e        3
f        4
g        4
h        4
```

I basically want a final dataframe like

```
col_1    col_2
a        1
b        1
c        2
d        3
f        4
g        4
```

Basically I cant use

```
my_df[my_df['col_2'].isin(my_list)]
```

since this will include all the rows. I want the first row that matches with each item on the list, but all the same count of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with original and helper DataFrame and filter by inner join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
my_list = [1,1,2,3,4,4]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_2':my_list})
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('col_2').cumcount()
my_df['g'] = my_df.groupby('col_2').cumcount()

df = my_df.merge(df1).drop('g', axis=1)

print (df)
  col_1  col_2
0     a      1
1     b      1
2     c      2
3     d      3
4     f      4
5     g      4
```